# Min 毋免: m̄-bián only, or possibly m̄-mián?

Tags: pronunciation, topolect, hokkien

This word is found in [爱拼才会赢](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y12_ecvVJgA&pbjreload=10), where I hear it as undoubtedly m̄-mián, yet when I look it up on [台湾闽南语常用词辞典](http://twblg.dict.edu.tw/holodict_new/index.html) or on [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E6%AF%8B%E5%85%8D), I only find the pronunciation m̄-bián.

So I was wondering: is he getting it wrong, or is there really an alternate pronunciation m̄-mián which is unrecorded in either dictionary?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This might be a case of assimilation, where the *b* nasalizes because of the *m* in front. Technically speaking, the syllable *mián* is "not allowed" because in most varieties of Hokkien, [b] and [m] are allophones of /b/, where [m] only shows up with a nasalized final, e.g., 滿 /buã/ → [muã ~ mua].

Answer (score 2):

When pronouncing, both of them are okay since we can tell what (s)he says. But it is informal and incorrect to say mián. We know that /p/ in hokkien is same as b in chinese pinyin, and /b/ in hokkien sounds near /m/. Therefore, /b/ sometimes sounds like /m/. But it is wrong to pronounce or write /b/ as /m/. [Pā-bián](http://twblg.dict.edu.tw/holodict_new/result_detail.jsp?n_no=53843&curpage=1&sample=%E5%85%8D&radiobutton=1&querytarget=1&limit=20&pagenum=1&rowcount=19) sounds like mián.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, a nasal onset consonant and a nasal coda can't appear in the same syllable in Taiwanese (Hokkien)(eg. Bân-lâm instead of Mân-nâm), so mián is illegal to be formed.